# Adding values together based upon creation of a formatted string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm just learning how to manipulate strings within SQL tables and am now trying to combine string manipulation with column value calculations.  My problem states that I limit a serial number, denoted by "xx-yyyyyyy", to its first two values (without the hyphen) and then add cost values together (that relate to these serial values) after creation of these new serial numbers.  However, when I add the cost values together, I am getting an incorrect result due to serial values not adding together (duplicate serial values within my output table).  My question is, how do I go about entering my code so that I have no duplicate serial values in my output and all values (excluding NULLs) are added together?

Example table that I am working with is like so:

```
 ____Serial____|____Cost____
1| xx-yyyyyy   | $aaa.bb
2| xx-yyyyyy   | $aaa.bb
3|    ...      |    ...
```

Here is my code that I have currently tried:

```
SELECT left(Serial, CHARINDEX('-', Serial)-1) AS NewSerial, sum(cost) AS TotalCost
FROM table
WHERE CHARINDEX('-', serial) > 0
GROUP BY Serial
ORDER BY TotalCost DESC
```

The results did add together cost values, but it did leave duplicate NewSerial values (which I assume is due to the GROUP BY clause).

```
Output (From my code):
_|___NewSerial____|____TotalCost____
1|     ab         |    $abc.de
2|     cd         |    $abc.de
3|     ab         |    $abc.de
4|     ef         |    $abc.de
5|     cd         |    $abc.de
```

How can I go about fixing/solving this issue within this area so that the NewSerial values all add together rather than stay separate like in my output?

Comment: If your code runs, it is not MySQL, most likely SQL Server so I fixed the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to repeat the expression in the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT left(Serial, CHARINDEX('-', Serial)-1) AS NewSerial, sum(cost) AS TotalCost
FROM table
WHERE CHARINDEX('-', serial) > 0
GROUP BY left(Serial, CHARINDEX('-', Serial)-1)
ORDER BY TotalCost DESC
```